# Error : relation does not exist, on greenplum database

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, hawq

I'm working on
PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum database 4.2.0 build 1)(HAWQ 1.2.1.0 build 10335).

I wrote a function like

```
create or replace function my_function ( 
...
    select exists(select 1 from my_table1 where condition) into result;
```

I tested it like

```
select my_function(params);
```

It can totally work!

Here is the problem, if I call the function like

```
select my_function(params) from my_table2;
```

Postgres told me you're wrong !

> ERROR: relation "my_table1" does not exist  (segXX sliceX xx.xx.xx:40003 pid=570406)

- Those tables and function are in same schema.
- I can access them.
- Both names are lower case.

So, help me please.

What I tried

- move those tables from my_schema to public
- move function to public
- add schema prefix like my_schema.my_table1.

---

Edited by 2015/04/19

Postgre -> Postgres

And I tried it like

```
select my_function(params) from pg_stat_activity;
```

It's OK.

If edit that function like

```
create or replace function my_function ( 
...
    select true into result;
```

It can work at any case.

Comment: If you need an answer to this, you could help it along by providing the complete function definition, the table definition, the schema for each object and what you get for `SHOW search_path`. Also: did you run all tests in the same session with the same settings? BTW, ["Postgre" is not an accepted name for Postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines).

Comment: @Cixy: Don't know if is your case, but are you creating "my_table1" as temporary table? AFAIK, Postgres 8.2 has a bug on it that raises when you try to select a temp table created by a function and selected by another one... the workaround is to "select" the temp table using "execute" statement. check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353438/postgres-doesnt-recognize-temp-table-in-function

Comment: @Christian B. Almeida. No, not a temporary table. Just normal

Comment: The 'exists' operator doesn't work with greenplum using 8.2 postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is function types.

By official docs

http://www.greenplumdba.com/greenplum-dba-faq/whatareimmutablestableandvolatilefunctionsingreenplum

Answer (score 1):

In Postgresql the functions usually run in the current search path of the session, so the problem might be that the schema `my_schema` is not in the current search path, when you run the function.

You can solve the problem by changing the declaration of your function to:

```
create or replace function my_function (...) ... as $$
 ....
$$ language plpgsql set search_path from current;
```

(I am not sure whether this works in the version 8)

If the clause `set search_path from current` does not work in 8.2, [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) an example how to set the search path temporarily within the function.

Comment: Thats clearly not it, since `tables and function are in same schema`. If `my_table2` can be found, the same is true for  `my_table1`.

Comment: It would help to have even a minimal example of compilable code that exhibits the problem, so that we could reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry to answer so late. We moved to different way.
I tested your answer today.
It can work (using the method in that link you gived).
Thank you so much!!!
Try to add bounty, but failed. I will try it again later.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It can NOT work.But thank you very much too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a way, not perfected but can work.

Since I can access the table at from segment. So, moving that function to from segment as a sub query will solved this problem.

SQL script likes below:

```
select t.*, f.* from my_table2 t join (select my_function(params)) f on true;
```

Still, all suggestions are welcome.